# not able to change name after copying a form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy and past a form within a project using Visual Studio.

I've managed to copy and past the form (right clicking in the Solution explorer > Copy; Right click again paste) I can change the name of the new form in the Solution explorer. But when I select the form [Design] I can't change the name property without changing the name property in the original form. Somehow the two are linked. What am I doing wrong?

I hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude all files of that form from project and then include again.

You can perform the include steps after reopen the project.

Comment: i agree, excluding files is a must. I actually debug all aspx pages in exclude mode. Include only when you need to deploy.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this. It worked and it was easier then I thought. Just for my understanding is there a purpose for the two staying interlinked after copying. It just seemed to create errors. Is there some higher level logic that would make this useful?

Comment: if it worked for you then accept the answer. It's a glitch of VS that it sometimes not able to link the files after pasting them.